# How can I see the full Node "require()" tree starting at a given file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to view a dependency tree of some sort, showing the various `require()`s starting at a particular file.  For example, if I have a `server.js` file like so:

```
// server.js
var myThing = require('./myThing');
```

and a `myThing.js` file like so:

```
// myThings.js
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

is there a way to see that `mongodb` is required by `server.js` without manually traversing through `myThing.js` ?

I'd love to see a tree something like `npm list` generates, eg:

```
alex@alex-pc ~/repos/test $ npm list
test@1.0.0 /home/alex/repos/test
├─┬ gulp@3.8.11
│ ├── archy@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ chalk@0.5.1
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
│ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
│ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@0.1.0
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
│ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@0.3.0
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
│ │ └── supports-color@0.2.0
│ ├── deprecated@0.0.1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the dependency tree using [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge)

Comment: very cool, I am mad-ge about it

Comment: it does "black madgic"

Answer (score 1):

[dependo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependo)

It is not sort, but visualize your files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any existing packages for this but you can create one using `module.parent` and `module.children` properties. Read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent). To get packages' versions you should read `package.json` of every package.

Also `npm` itself can contain useful code. You can try to get it here - https://github.com/npm/npm

Comment: How will that work with `require('./myThing')` which is just a single `myThing.js` file - not an entire package with a `package.json` ?

Comment: The `myThing.js` will be in `server.js`'s module.children, but without any `package.json`. So, by this fact you can detect it's not a package.