# List of all files required by a Node script

Tags: node.js

Any thoughts on how I could get an array of file paths required (recursively) by a Node script? For example, given:

a.js

```
module.exports = {};
```

b.js

```
module.exports = {
   a : require('./a.js');
};
```

c.js

```
const b = require('./b.js');

//etc. etc.
```

I'd like to run something like:

```
someAwesomeFunctionOrLibrary(require('./c.js'));  // ["./b.js","./a.js"]
```

Comment: Related: [How can I see the full nodejs “require()” tree starting at a given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548132/how-can-i-see-the-full-nodejs-require-tree-starting-at-a-given-file) – [dependency-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-tree) seems to be another option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to traverse [`module.children`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_children) recursively.

```
var listModulePaths = (mod) => {
  for (var child of mod.children) {
    console.log(child.id)
    listModulePaths(child)
  }
}

listModulePaths(module)
```